# Is there a way to create disk partitions on Vagrant vm?

Tags: partitioning, vagrant, ansible

I have tried everything so far but without result. I have a ansible role which creates partitions on the machine. I'm trying to set up the partitions on the vm but i can't (i'm using libvirt as provider).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdb', :bus => 'scsi'
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdc', :bus => 'scsi'
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdd', :bus => 'scsi'
  end
  config.vm.box = "roboxes/centos9s"
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    SHELL
  end
```